# Setting one field at a time?

Tags: awk, gawk

Trying to turn some butchered data into bar delimited, unbutchered data...

here's some sample data

```
asd1276vdjs12897364vsk Tue Apr  2 08:19:12 2013 [pid 3] [words] FAIL UPLOAD: Client "00.005.006.006", "/0801NSJH.bbf", 0.00Kbyte/sec
```

into

```
asd1276vdjs12897364vsk|Tue Apr  2 08:19:12 2013|[pid 3]|[words]|FAIL UPLOAD: Client "00.005.006.006"|"/0801NSJH.bbf"|0.00Kbyte/sec
```

The regex's are simple enough, but I don't know how to say `first field = regex, second field = regex` etc.

This sed is functional but kind of hacky, I'd like to make it work in gawk.

```
sed 's/ Sun/|Sun/'
sed 's/ Mon/|Mon/'
sed 's/ Tue/|Tue/'
sed 's/ Wed/|Wed/'
sed 's/ Thu/|Thu/'
sed 's/ Fri/|Fri/'
sed 's/ Sat/|Sat/'
sed 's/ Sun/|Sun/'
sed -e 's% \[%|\[%g' -e 's%\] %\]|%g' -e 's%, %|%g'
```

Comment: It's quite find to find rules for such a regex.

Comment: I removed the regex tag. This is a question about awk/gawk.

Comment: The problem with this question is there isn't a nice solution, I could provide a solution that fixes the example, I would probably use `printf` to format the input but I **guarantee** other lines in the file will not match exactly format/no. of fields as the example.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat tst.awk
{ print gensub(/\
([^[:space:]]+)[[:space:]]+\
([^[]+)[[:space:]]+\
([[][^]]+[]])[[:space:]]+\
([[][^]]+[]])[[:space:]]+\
([^,]+),[[:space:]]+\
([^,]+),[[:space:]]+\
/,
"\\1|\\2|\\3|\\4|\\5|\\6|","")
}
$ awk -f tst.awk file
asd1276vdjs12897364vsk|Tue Apr  2 08:19:12 2013|[pid 3]|[words]|FAIL UPLOAD: Client "00.005.006.006"|"/0801NSJH.bbf"|0.00Kbyte/sec
```